# Read error in Firebase Database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored a value in a node `Last-book-ID ="-1"`
when ever I try to read it the value is always shown as 0 why ?
can anyone suggest where am I am going wrong
People please help [image: The JSONTree] [image: The code used to fetch the data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your method getLastBookId() will always return the value of bid[0] which has not yet been initialized to anything.  If you're displaying that, it will always be 0.

When you call addListenerForSingleValueEvent(), it's setting up an *asynchronous* callback that will happen at some later point in time, after the database query has completed.  So it most likely will not yet have populated bid[0] by the time your method returns.

You need to change your thinking and probably your app design a bit to work in line with this... for example, at the end of the onDataChange() callback, make the UI update to display the value where it's needed, etc.

Comment: Thanks Sir. You dont know how much you helped me thank you sooo much.
I was even thinking that the data retrieved from firebase was on a background thread but you made that sure thanks Sir once again